# AzureFileShareConfiguration mount drive disconnected

Tags: azure-storage, azure-batch, azure-storage-files

I am trying to create a Pool using Azure Batch . I have uploaded content to Azure Storage using File Shares.
I would like my Pool to mount this Azure File Share as virtual file system (ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/virtual-file-mount#mount-a-virtual-file-system-on-a-pool ).

I am creating AzureFileShareConfiguration object using code:

```
   mount_configuration=batchmodels.MountConfiguration(azure_file_share_configuration=batchmodels.AzureFileShareConfiguration(
account_name="mystorage",
azure_file_url="https://mystorage.file.core.windows.net/my-share1",
account_key="mystorage/key==",
relative_mount_path="S"
)
)
```

Using this, I get "CMDKEY: Credentials added successfully" in fsmounts. But when I RDP to the node in the pool, the S drive appears "Disconnected".

My Azure batch package versions are:
azure-batch==8.0.0
azure-common==1.1.24

Can you please help diagnose the issue or suggest the right usage?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2):

I think this is windows VM you are trying?, just by looking at the drive letter `: )`.

**Here is the key issue with RDP permissions** is different then your Batch level model when your code runs and mount.

At Batch level when you mount your `Drive:` and you can see it via your `Start task` then it is working. i.e. that a Batch level permissioning model and when you RDP into Node it will be as a "user" you are logged-in.  If you want to see via UI RDP user you should re-run the command from your RDP login to update that you have key to see that drive.

Although having said that try it with `/persistent:Yes` as mount_options.

- **The best test is going to be** -- You mount the drive and from your start task go to the mounted directory via : `S:\\Whatever_file.txt` or read the mounted file which will add the result in your `stdout.txt` of batch node or might be just `dir` it or something.

**Rest extra stuff below**

try with this `mount_options value`

Also specifically this will help for various SMB version et. al. support: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-windows  and I think this you already know : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/virtual-file-mount#azure-files-share

> In order to use an Azure file share outside of the Azure region it is
> hosted in, such as on-premises or in a different Azure region, the OS
> must support SMB 3.0.

So add this to your API and give it a try:

`MountOptions = "/persistent:Yes"` i.e. `mount_options = "/persistent:Yes"`

Also: key needs to be Storage account Key, i.e. it should not start with `mystorage/key` `:)` but it could be you hiding it, so just a mention and fyi.

Sample code:

I think SDK you have is python?

```
   mount_configuration=batchmodels.MountConfiguration(azure_file_share_configuration=batchmodels.AzureFileShareConfiguration(
     account_name="mystorage",
     azure_file_url="https://mystorage.file.core.windows.net/my-share1",
     account_key="mystorage/key==",
     relative_mount_path="S",
     mount_options = "/persistent:Yes"
)
```

hope this helps!

Comment: @Tat_innit This looks helpful, but now I am no longer looking at that requirement.

Answer (score 0):

`relative_mount_path`: The relative path on the compute node where the file system will be mounted. All file systems are mounted relative to the Batch mounts directory, accessible via the `AZ_BATCH_NODE_MOUNTS_DIR` environment variable.

[Azure Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/virtual-file-mount#azure-files-share) is the standard Azure cloud file system offering. To learn more about how to get any of the parameters in the mount configuration code sample, see Use an [Azure Files share](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-windows).

Comment: Please refer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59692400/relativemountpath-under-azure-batch-pool as well as https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/virtual-file-mount . relative_mount_path is supposed to be a network drive letter for Azuer File Share